# How to restart a css animation without using void?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, keyframe

With this line removed, how would I be able to restart an animation after the Home / X button is clicked?

```
void theBody.offsetWidth;
```

[image]

As you can see in the snippet, or jsfiddle, currently how it works is, after the **X** is clicked, there is an animation that occurs.

https://jsfiddle.net/hdycz159/

How would I be able to do that using CSS replacing the javascript?

I would be removing this line: `void theBody.offsetWidth;`

I'm looking to have the code work with the void line removed from the code: `void theBody.offsetWidth;`

Also it would have to be a way that doesn't use `setTimeout`

**javascript**

```
function showHome() {
    const theActive = document.querySelector(".with-curtain.active");
    const theHides = document.querySelectorAll(".hide");
    const theBody = document.querySelector("body");
    theActive.classList.remove("active");
    theHides.forEach(function (removeHide) {
        removeHide.classList.remove("hide");
    });

    theBody.classList.remove("fade");
    void theBody.offsetWidth; //restart animation
    theBody.classList.add("fade");
}
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  background: #353198;
}

.fade{
  animation: fade 2s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```js
const manageCover = (function makeManageCover() {
    const config = {};

    function show(el) {
        el.classList.remove("hide");
    }

    function hide(el) {
        el.classList.add("hide");
    }

    function hideAll(elements) {
        elements.forEach(hide);
    }

    function showCovers(playButton) {
        const cover = playButton.parentElement;
        cover.classList.add("active");
        show(cover);
    }

    function coverClickHandler(evt) {
        hideAll(config.containers);
        const cover = evt.currentTarget;
        showCovers(cover);
    }

    function showHome() {
        const theActive = document.querySelector(".with-curtain.active");
        const theHides = document.querySelectorAll(".hide");
        const theBody = document.querySelector("body");
        theActive.classList.remove("active");
        theHides.forEach(function (removeHide) {
            removeHide.classList.remove("hide");
        });

        theBody.classList.remove("fade");
        void theBody.offsetWidth; //restart animation
        theBody.classList.add("fade");
    }

    function homeClickHandler(evt) {
        const home = evt.currentTarget;
        showHome(home);
    }

    function addClickToButtons(playButtons) {
        playButtons.forEach(function addEventHandler(playButton) {
            playButton.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
        });
    }

    function addClickToHome(goHome) {
        goHome.forEach(function addEventHandler(goHome) {
            goHome.addEventListener("click", homeClickHandler);
        });
    }

    function addCoverHandler(coverSelector, handler) {
        const cover = document.querySelector(coverSelector);
        cover.addEventListener("click", handler);
    }


    function init(selectors) {
        config.containers = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.container);
        const playButtons = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.playButton);
        addClickToButtons(playButtons);
        const goHome = document.querySelectorAll(".home");
        addClickToHome(goHome);

    }

    return {
        addCoverHandler,
        init
    };
}());

function combinePlayerOptions(options1 = {}, options2 = {}) {
    const combined = Object.assign({}, options1, options2);
    Object.keys(options1).forEach(function checkObjects(prop) {
        if (typeof options1[prop] === "object") {
            combined[prop] = Object.assign({}, options1[prop], options2[prop]);
        }
    });
    return combined;
}

const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {
    const players = [];

    const tag = document.createElement("script");
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
    const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        const player = event.target;
        player.setVolume(100);
    }

    function addPlayer(video, settings) {
        const defaults = {
            height: 360,
            host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
            videoId: video.dataset.id,
            width: 640
        };
        defaults.events = {
            "onReady": onPlayerReady
        };

        const playerOptions = combinePlayerOptions(defaults, settings);
        const player = new YT.Player(video, playerOptions);
        players.push(player);
        return player;
    }

    return {
        addPlayer
    };
}());

const managePlayer = (function makeManagePlayer() {
    const defaults = {
        playerVars: {
            autoplay: 0,
            controls: 1,
            disablekb: 1,
            enablejsapi: 1,
            fs: 0,
            iv_load_policy: 3
        }
    };

    function show(el) {
        el.classList.remove("hide");
    }

    function createPlayer(videoWrapper, settings = {}) {
        const video = videoWrapper.querySelector(".video");
        const playerOptions = combinePlayerOptions(defaults, settings);
        return videoPlayer.addPlayer(video, playerOptions);
    }

    function createCoverClickHandler(playerSettings) {
        return function coverClickHandler(evt) {
            const cover = evt.currentTarget;
            const wrapper = cover.nextElementSibling;
            show(wrapper);
            const player = createPlayer(wrapper, playerSettings);
            wrapper.player = player;
        };
    }

    function addPlayer(coverSelector, playerSettings) {
        const clickHandler = createCoverClickHandler(playerSettings);
        manageCover.addCoverHandler(coverSelector, clickHandler);
    }

    return {
        add: addPlayer
    };
}());

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    managePlayer.add(".playa", {});

    managePlayer.add(".playb", {
        playerVars: {
            playlist: "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g"
        }
    });
    managePlayer.add(".playc", {});

    manageCover.init({
        container: ".container",
        playButton: ".thePlay"
    });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #353198;
}

.fade {
  animation: fade 2s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container.active {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  animation: fadebody 5s ease 0s forwards;
  background-size: 165px 165px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(teal 5px, #0000 5px), linear-gradient(90deg, teal 5px, #0000 5px), linear-gradient(black 10px, #0000 10px 160px, black 160px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 10px, #0000 10px 160px, black 160px), linear-gradient(orange 15px, #0000 15px 155px, orange 155px), linear-gradient(90deg, orange 15px, #0000 15px 155px, orange 155px), linear-gradient(black 20px, #0000 20px 150px, black 150px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 20px, #0000 20px 150px, black 150px), linear-gradient(teal 25px, #0000 25px 145px, teal 145px), linear-gradient(90deg, teal 25px, #0000 25px 145px, teal 145px), linear-gradient(black 30px, #0000 30px 140px, black 140px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 30px, #0000 30px 140px, black 140px), linear-gradient(orange 35px, #0000 35px 135px, orange 135px), linear-gradient(90deg, orange 35px, #0000 35px 135px, orange 135px), linear-gradient(black 40px, #0000 40px 130px, black 130px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 40px, #0000 40px 130px, black 130px), linear-gradient(teal 45px, #0000 45px 125px, teal 125px), linear-gradient(90deg, teal 45px, #0000 45px 125px, teal 125px), linear-gradient(black 50px, #0000 50px 120px, black 120px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 50px, #0000 50px 120px, black 120px), linear-gradient(orange 55px, #0000 55px 115px, orange 115px), linear-gradient(90deg, orange 55px, #0000 55px 115px, orange 115px), linear-gradient(black 60px, #0000 60px 110px, black 110px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 60px, #0000 60px 110px, black 110px), linear-gradient(teal 65px, #0000 65px 105px, teal 105px), linear-gradient(90deg, teal 65px, #0000 65px 105px, teal 105px), linear-gradient(black 70px, #0000 70px 100px, black 100px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 70px, #0000 70px 100px, black 100px), linear-gradient(orange 75px, #0000 75px 95px, orange 95px), linear-gradient(90deg, orange 75px, #0000 75px 95px, orange 95px), linear-gradient(black 80px, #0000 80px 90px, black 90px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 80px, #0000 80px 90px, black 90px), linear-gradient(teal, teal);
}

.inner-container {
  display: none;
}

.container.active .thePlay {
  display: none;
}

.container.active .inner-container {
  display: flex;
}

.container.active .inner-container.curtain {
  display: block;
}

@keyframes fadebody {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.playa,
.playb,
.playc {
  margin: auto 20px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
}

.playa {
  fill: red;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

.playb {
  fill: blue;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

.playc {
  fill: orange;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

button.thePlay {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.home {
  position: fixed;
  right: 12px;
  top: 12px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: black;
}

.home::before,
.home::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: #d4001e;
  width: 30px;
  height: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.home::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.home::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.curtain {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: auto;
  flex: 1 0 0%;
}

.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(50% + 1px);
  /* rounding error fix */
  top: 0%;
  transition: all ease 10s;
  /*background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/600");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-left {
  left: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(91, 96, 106);*/
}

.panel-right {
  right: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(229, 211, 211);*/
}

.panel-left::before,
.panel-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.curtain2 .panel-left::before,
.curtain2 .panel-right::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
}

.curtain3 .panel-left::before,
.curtain3 .panel-right::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
}

.panel-right::before {
  left: -100%;
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-left {
  animation: curtain1 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain1 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain2 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain3 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain2 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

@keyframes curtain3 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body class="fade">
   <div class="outer">
      <div class="container with-curtain">
         <button class="playa thePlay" pointer-events="none">
            <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
               <g id="play">
                  <title>Play</title>
                  <circle cx="32" cy="32" r="32" fill="transparent" pointer-events="visiblePainted"  />
                  <path d="M25.6,46.4L44.8,32L25.6,17.6V46.4z M32,0C14.3,0,0,14.3,0,32s14.3,32,32,32s32-14.3,32-32S49.7,0,32,0z
                     M32,57.6C17.9,57.6,6.4,46.1,6.4,32S17.9,6.4,32,6.4S57.6,17.9,57.6,32S46.1,57.6,32,57.6z" />
               </g>
            </svg>
         </button>
         <div class="inner-container curtain curtain1">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
               <div class="wrapa">
                  <div class="video video-frame" data-id="CHahce95B1g"></div>
               </div>
               <div class="panel-left"></div>
               <div class="panel-right"></div>
            </div>
            <button class="home" aria-label="Close"></button>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container with-curtain">
         <button class="playb thePlay">
            <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
               <use href="#play" />
            </svg>
         </button>
         <div class="inner-container curtain curtain2">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
               <div class="wrapa">
                  <div class="video video-frame"></div>
               </div>
               <div class="panel-left"></div>
               <div class="panel-right"></div>
            </div>
            <button class="home" aria-label="Close"></button>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container with-curtain">
         <button class="playc thePlay">
            <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
               <use href="#play" />
            </svg>
         </button>
         <div class="inner-container curtain curtain3">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
               <div class="wrapa">
                  <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
               </div>
               <div class="panel-left"></div>
               <div class="panel-right"></div>
            </div>
            <button class="home" aria-label="Close"></button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you completely wish do it with css?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the animation property via JavaScript to "none" and then set a timeout that changes the property to "", so it inherits from the CSS again.

```js
const manageCover = (function makeManageCover() {
  const config = {};

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function hideAll(elements) {
    elements.forEach(hide);
  }

  function showCovers(playButton) {
    const cover = playButton.parentElement;
    cover.classList.add("active");
    show(cover);
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    hideAll(config.containers);
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    showCovers(cover);
  }

  function showHome() {
    const theActive = document.querySelector(".with-curtain.active");
    const theHides = document.querySelectorAll(".hide");
    const theBody = document.querySelector("body");
    theActive.classList.remove("active");
    theHides.forEach(function(removeHide) {
      removeHide.classList.remove("hide");
    });

    // theBody.classList.remove("fade");
    // void theBody.offsetWidth; //restart animation
    // theBody.classList.add("fade");
    theBody.style.webkitAnimation = 'none';
    setTimeout(function() {
      theBody.style.webkitAnimation = '';
    }, 0);
  }

  function homeClickHandler(evt) {
    const home = evt.currentTarget;
    showHome(home);
  }

  function addClickToButtons(playButtons) {
    playButtons.forEach(function addEventHandler(playButton) {
      playButton.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
    });
  }

  function addClickToHome(goHome) {
    goHome.forEach(function addEventHandler(goHome) {
      goHome.addEventListener("click", homeClickHandler);
    });
  }

  function addCoverHandler(coverSelector, handler) {
    const cover = document.querySelector(coverSelector);
    cover.addEventListener("click", handler);
  }


  function init(selectors) {
    config.containers = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.container);
    const playButtons = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.playButton);
    addClickToButtons(playButtons);
    const goHome = document.querySelectorAll(".home");
    addClickToHome(goHome);

  }

  return {
    addCoverHandler,
    init
  };
}());

function combinePlayerOptions(options1 = {}, options2 = {}) {
  const combined = Object.assign({}, options1, options2);
  Object.keys(options1).forEach(function checkObjects(prop) {
    if (typeof options1[prop] === "object") {
      combined[prop] = Object.assign({}, options1[prop], options2[prop]);
    }
  });
  return combined;
}

const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {
  const players = [];

  const tag = document.createElement("script");
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    player.setVolume(100);
  }

  function addPlayer(video, settings) {
    const defaults = {
      height: 360,
      host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
      videoId: video.dataset.id,
      width: 640
    };
    defaults.events = {
      "onReady": onPlayerReady
    };

    const playerOptions = combinePlayerOptions(defaults, settings);
    const player = new YT.Player(video, playerOptions);
    players.push(player);
    return player;
  }

  return {
    addPlayer
  };
}());

const managePlayer = (function makeManagePlayer() {
  const defaults = {
    playerVars: {
      autoplay: 0,
      controls: 1,
      disablekb: 1,
      enablejsapi: 1,
      fs: 0,
      iv_load_policy: 3
    }
  };

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function createPlayer(videoWrapper, settings = {}) {
    const video = videoWrapper.querySelector(".video");
    const playerOptions = combinePlayerOptions(defaults, settings);
    return videoPlayer.addPlayer(video, playerOptions);
  }

  function createCoverClickHandler(playerSettings) {
    return function coverClickHandler(evt) {
      const cover = evt.currentTarget;
      const wrapper = cover.nextElementSibling;
      show(wrapper);
      const player = createPlayer(wrapper, playerSettings);
      wrapper.player = player;
    };
  }

  function addPlayer(coverSelector, playerSettings) {
    const clickHandler = createCoverClickHandler(playerSettings);
    manageCover.addCoverHandler(coverSelector, clickHandler);
  }

  return {
    add: addPlayer
  };
}());

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  managePlayer.add(".playa", {});

  managePlayer.add(".playb", {
    playerVars: {
      playlist: "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g"
    }
  });
  managePlayer.add(".playc", {});

  manageCover.init({
    container: ".container",
    playButton: ".thePlay"
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #353198;
}

.fade {
  animation: fade 2s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container.active {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  animation: fadebody 5s ease 0s forwards;
  background-size: 165px 165px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(teal 5px, #0000 5px), linear-gradient(90deg, teal 5px, #0000 5px), linear-gradient(black 10px, #0000 10px 160px, black 160px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 10px, #0000 10px 160px, black 160px), linear-gradient(orange 15px, #0000 15px 155px, orange 155px), linear-gradient(90deg, orange 15px, #0000 15px 155px, orange 155px), linear-gradient(black 20px, #0000 20px 150px, black 150px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 20px, #0000 20px 150px, black 150px), linear-gradient(teal 25px, #0000 25px 145px, teal 145px), linear-gradient(90deg, teal 25px, #0000 25px 145px, teal 145px), linear-gradient(black 30px, #0000 30px 140px, black 140px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 30px, #0000 30px 140px, black 140px), linear-gradient(orange 35px, #0000 35px 135px, orange 135px), linear-gradient(90deg, orange 35px, #0000 35px 135px, orange 135px), linear-gradient(black 40px, #0000 40px 130px, black 130px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 40px, #0000 40px 130px, black 130px), linear-gradient(teal 45px, #0000 45px 125px, teal 125px), linear-gradient(90deg, teal 45px, #0000 45px 125px, teal 125px), linear-gradient(black 50px, #0000 50px 120px, black 120px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 50px, #0000 50px 120px, black 120px), linear-gradient(orange 55px, #0000 55px 115px, orange 115px), linear-gradient(90deg, orange 55px, #0000 55px 115px, orange 115px), linear-gradient(black 60px, #0000 60px 110px, black 110px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 60px, #0000 60px 110px, black 110px), linear-gradient(teal 65px, #0000 65px 105px, teal 105px), linear-gradient(90deg, teal 65px, #0000 65px 105px, teal 105px), linear-gradient(black 70px, #0000 70px 100px, black 100px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 70px, #0000 70px 100px, black 100px), linear-gradient(orange 75px, #0000 75px 95px, orange 95px), linear-gradient(90deg, orange 75px, #0000 75px 95px, orange 95px), linear-gradient(black 80px, #0000 80px 90px, black 90px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 80px, #0000 80px 90px, black 90px), linear-gradient(teal, teal);
}

.inner-container {
  display: none;
}

.container.active .thePlay {
  display: none;
}

.container.active .inner-container {
  display: flex;
}

.container.active .inner-container.curtain {
  display: block;
}

@keyframes fadebody {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.playa,
.playb,
.playc {
  margin: auto 20px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
}

.playa {
  fill: red;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

.playb {
  fill: blue;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

.playc {
  fill: orange;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

button.thePlay {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.home {
  position: fixed;
  right: 12px;
  top: 12px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: black;
}

.home::before,
.home::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: #d4001e;
  width: 30px;
  height: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.home::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.home::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.curtain {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: auto;
  flex: 1 0 0%;
}

.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(50% + 1px);
  /* rounding error fix */
  top: 0%;
  transition: all ease 10s;
  /*background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/600");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-left {
  left: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(91, 96, 106);*/
}

.panel-right {
  right: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(229, 211, 211);*/
}

.panel-left::before,
.panel-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.curtain2 .panel-left::before,
.curtain2 .panel-right::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
}

.curtain3 .panel-left::before,
.curtain3 .panel-right::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
}

.panel-right::before {
  left: -100%;
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-left {
  animation: curtain1 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain1 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain2 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain3 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain2 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

@keyframes curtain3 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body class="fade">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="container with-curtain">
      <button class="playa thePlay" pointer-events="none">
            <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
               <g id="play">
                  <title>Play</title>
                  <circle cx="32" cy="32" r="32" fill="transparent" pointer-events="visiblePainted"  />
                  <path d="M25.6,46.4L44.8,32L25.6,17.6V46.4z M32,0C14.3,0,0,14.3,0,32s14.3,32,32,32s32-14.3,32-32S49.7,0,32,0z
                     M32,57.6C17.9,57.6,6.4,46.1,6.4,32S17.9,6.4,32,6.4S57.6,17.9,57.6,32S46.1,57.6,32,57.6z" />
               </g>
            </svg>
         </button>
      <div class="inner-container curtain curtain1">
        <div class="ratio-keeper">
          <div class="wrapa">
            <div class="video video-frame" data-id="CHahce95B1g"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
        <button class="home" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container with-curtain">
      <button class="playb thePlay">
            <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
               <use href="#play" />
            </svg>
         </button>
      <div class="inner-container curtain curtain2">
        <div class="ratio-keeper">
          <div class="wrapa">
            <div class="video video-frame"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
        <button class="home" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container with-curtain">
      <button class="playc thePlay">
            <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
               <use href="#play" />
            </svg>
         </button>
      <div class="inner-container curtain curtain3">
        <div class="ratio-keeper">
          <div class="wrapa">
            <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
        <button class="home" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I was told the delay you need varies between browsers so its not 100% safe. Is there a different way it can be written without setTimeout?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/47889/235622)